# Is there a way to automatically create a mind map using Freemind and Java code ?

Tags: java, freemind, mindmap

Is there a way to create a mind map automatically using Java code and using Freemind ?

Comment: what do u mean "automatically" ??

Comment: What i mean is , is there any way to write a code in Java that will create the map without having to create in Freemind .

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom scripts in Java inside Freemind that can create your Mindmap

http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Example_scripts